# Recovering part of a Word document

Tags: data-recovery, microsoft-word-2013

Last week, a friend of mine was typing in a Microsoft word document while driving (being driven), and reports "hitting a bump in the road" and losing the content of the document.
I imagine that what happened was that all that text got selected, and then erased with one press of <kbd>del</kbd> or <kbd>backspace</kbd>, but I can only conjecture.
(The document has since been closed)

**What can I do to get the contents of this document back?**

I've already tried `File >> Versions`, but no luck -- apparently, there are no saved earlier versions of this document.

Is there anything that can be done, or is this document gone forever?

He's using Word 2013, on Windows 8.1.

Comment: Related (but different!) cross-site question: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/13388/7730

Comment: If he wasn't using auto-save, this could be tricky. Try looking in temp directories for something close to the timestamp of the erasure?

Comment: @barrycarter I might try that....thanks for the recommendation!

Answer (score -3):

If auto save was enabled immediately turn off the computer and connect the primary HDD to an EXTERNAL operating system and open up the off disk file system.

This will take SEVERAL hours to recover and find the actual file.
I wouldn't spend the time on this, more than likely they are lying because ctr + Z would undo the erasing.

Comment: `ctrl-Z` would **not** undo the erasing, because he has since closed the document. I thought I was clear on that in my question, but I guess not....what do you propose to do in another OS? I can boot several, but what should be done once there?

Comment: I did not say Ctrl + Z was the solution, i suggest you read responses thoroughly. The solution is to get the removed AUTO-Saved file off the disk before it is overwritten. When files are removed by the operating system they are only moved off of the file system and marked as free space to be over written when needed. Hint -Data recovery- If data recovery is not possible in this case then there is no possible way for you to recover the data loss.

Comment: I apologize, but that was not clear from your answer. You may want to [edit] that in so your answer makes sense. I say this with all due respect, and I really appreciate the fact that you are trying to help me.

Comment: If I understand what you mean in your comment, why should that "take several hours"? ....just boot the other OS, find the temp file, and go from there....? Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Data recovery is a messy process, when a file is moved from the file system it is stripped of its file information data, and renamed to a volume label. So identifying the direct file will be tedious(there are THOUSANDS of files that are off the file system). Please do some research here: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/filerecovery/f/recover-deleted-files-how-to.htm